# TSql dbcc checkident command fails when database exists

Tags: t-sql, ssms

Running the `dbcc checkident` command in SQL Server Management Studio, trying to reset the identity column. As you can see in the picture below clearly my table exists and the schema is the default dbo. But when attempt to execute:

```
dbcc checkident (Article, RESEED, 4);
```

I get the following response from the query:

```
Msg 2501, Level 16, State 45, Line 1
Cannot find a table or object with the name "Article". Check the system catalog.
```

[image: evidence my table exists]

This happens for every table in all of my databases. But this one is the specific one I'm trying to use. The table does have data in it. What can I do/check?

Comment: Does using Quotes help??
dbcc checkident ('dbo.Article', RESEED, 4);
And I assume you have the correct database selected?

Comment: `create table dbo.Article(a int identity(1,1));dbcc checkident (Article, RESEED, 4);` works for me. Are you sure `dbo` is **your** login's default schema, that your login has sufficient permissions to do this and that you have the right database context selected?

Comment: @Martin- I don't know what you mean by database context selected. I'm new to SQL Server so I'm flying by seat of pants using it.

Comment: @DaveShaw no using quotes and just putting `dbo.Article` both fail the same message. It just puts quotes around the name in the error message

Comment: @Matt - How are you running this Script? In SSMS? If so do you have `mattsblog` selected in the dropdown list? You can run `use mattsblog;` to be sure that it is in the right context.

Comment: @Martin I didn't initially but I just tried selecting it from the Object Explorer in SSMS and then executing the command and it still failed same way

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by selecting it from the Object Explorer. Can you try running `SELECT DB_NAME()` in your script window and see what it says?

Comment: its one column with 'master' in it. So obviously thats why it's not finding the tables. but what do I do to select my table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments it seems your script window is running in the context of the `master` database. You need to change the context to your database either by changing the value in the dropdown or running the below.

```
use mattsblog;

dbcc checkident (Article, RESEED, 4);
```

NB: In SSMS each script window represents a different connection. You can look in the status bar to see things like the current database context, user name, and `spid` for each window.

Comment: haha it had to be that easy didn't it ;) Thanks for the quick detective work!

Comment: That was my second question in the comments :p